# How to listen to button click from other activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-button

I have 2 activity.

1.activity layout-> one.xml

2.activity layout-> two.xml

There is a button in one.xml

I want to add set on click function in 2.activity

But it gives error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.ehlyt.droid, PID: 21876
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(....
```

so how can I do this?

thanks in advance

Comment: At first address the `NullPointerException` that you are getting. And you are trying to set click listener from another activity which should not be done. Explain what are you actually trying to achieve and post what you have done so far

Comment: I need to add that to 2.activity How can I do that, I try to inflate but not achive

Comment: What a mess! What you're trying to achieve?

Comment: just call on click action from button another activty

Comment: can you explain a use case?

Comment: What you are trying to can be achieved by using a [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

Comment: don't you know it is NOT possible in the way you've been trying to do that? Again, what kind of info you'd like to pass between Activities?

Comment: I do not call another activity. 1.activity is fragment and 2. is child activity

Comment: the button must be in 1.activty layout. And I need to action on second activity